# Aghhh!!! I lost interface builder to code

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface, builder, version-editor

So this is probably a noob question, but my interface builder turned into red code.  I think the "version editor" somehow did it, but I just want it back.  I am a noob and can't write the interface in code.  Any help?

Comment: What do you mean `turned into red code` ? click the .xib file again - you can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean in the left pane that lists your files, the .xib filename turned red? That means the file is gone, and usually XCode didn't do it, or it would have removed it from the list too. Maybe you deleted it from the file system, maybe it was done by a version control system as you are suggesting. If you have it in a version control system you should be able to get back the last version of it.

If all else fails, File > New > New File. Choose User Interface under iOS, and pick usually View. Re-create your interface using Interface Builder from scratch.